# Outline list item when child anchor tag is getting focus

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background of the list item when the focus is on the anchor tag. It works on hover, How can I change the background during focus?

**I want to make the list more accessible so that even when the user focuses on the anchor tag, the respective list item should also highlight**

```css
.main-list{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.main-list .list-item{
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-list .list-item:hover, .main-list .list-item:focus{
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-list">
 <li class="list-item"><a href="#">dummy text</a></li>
 <li class="list-item"><a href="#">dummy text</a></li>
 <li class="list-item"><a href="#">dummy text</a></li>
 <li class="list-item"><a href="#">dummy text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you want to consider focus of `a` (duplicate 2 (here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46406959/8620333) and 3) ... If you want the focus on li (duplicate 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within). Disclaimer: how compatible do you need it to be?

```css
.main-list{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.main-list .list-item{
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-list .list-item:hover, .main-list .list-item:focus-within{
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-list">
 <li class="list-item"><a href="#">dummy text</a></li>
 <li class="list-item"><a href="#">dummy text</a></li>
 <li class="list-item"><a href="#">dummy text</a></li>
 <li class="list-item"><a href="#">dummy text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a css solution. Any support for IE and edge?

Comment: Edge support will arrive as soon as the Edge version based on Blink is released. IE, well, no.

Comment: But why don't you simply move all the styles for <li> to the <a>s inside, like the padding and stuff. Then the <a>s will cover the <li>s completely and you can use `:focus` on the <a>s.